# Inconsistent line ends in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, line-endings

I use Notepad++ v6.7.5. I understand that the Edit->EOL Conversion setting controls how Notepad++ saves files. I have it set to "Windows Format," which should make it force every line end to <cr><lf> when a file is saved. And it does, about 99% of the time.

I edited a source file that came from a Linux system, presumably with Linux line ends. After some editing I submitted it to a source control system that validates line ends. It reported about a dozen errors. I made Notepad++ display the line end characters and found that about half of these errors were line endings with <lf> only, like Linux; the rest were <cr> only, like nothing I know of.

Most (maybe all) of these errors were in lines that I created, i.e. the line endings were keyboarded in Notepad++, not found in the initial state of the file.

Does anyone know the cause of this problem, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Toggle `EOL Conversion` from one state to the other. Your final toggle, for Windows, will have all EOL set to `<cr><lf>`. You may need to toggle a couple of times depending on the number of lines in the file.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, "EOL Conversion" performs an operation on a file -- it doesn't set the editor's state. Is that correct? And does "a couple of times" mean "twice" (my meaning) or "a few times" (my wife's meaning)? "A few times" would be awkward, because there seems to be no easy way to tell when the line ends have all been normalized.

Comment: First, select View/ShowSymbol/ShowAllCharacters. Next, SelectAll (ctrl A). Then select Edit/EOL Conversion/{select any option that is not grey}. Repeat but select a new option, such as `Windows Format`. In a very large file, I have noticed that every EOL marker is not changed on the first pass. But if you follow the process 2-3x max, all EOL marks will be changed to your selected format. If the last line has the target EOL marker you are good to go. I've never seen a case where intermediate lines have a different EOL marker than the final line when following this process.